# Why does phoenix install will elixir 1.4 when I only have 1.7.3 installed on the machine?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Realised that the application.ex file was still using `Supervisor.Spec` - which is deprecated as mentioned in the docs - https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html

So I then realised that no matter how I create a new `phoenix - 1.3.4` project. The elixir version in the `mix.exs` is set to `1.4`?

Is this right?

I really want to use `1.7.x` as I would like to start the project on a later version.

Could anyone help clarify please?

Comment: That just comes from a template in the Phoenix installer. It just means that Phoenix itself works with Elixir 1.4+. You are free to change the value in the mix file to move to whichever version of Elixir you want. You are also not required to use that version in the mix file. It just means that you are using the features that are only available in Elixir `x.y`+